# What is the best Scala library for writing/reading PNG image files?

Tags: image, scala, file, png, media

What is the best Scala library for writing/reading PNG image files?   I'm looking for the Scala-equivalent of  libpng (c++) and  pypng (Python)

Comment: probably a Java library rather than something Scala-specific (though I'm not sure the latter doesn't exist)

Comment: It may be better to ask in **reddit** or **gitter**.

Answer (score 0):

As java libraries can be used in scala; So you can use java library [`javax imageIO`] or [`java awt`] or both. You can find plenty of their examples on internet. Here I'm sharing one.

Below is sample code for the same.

```
import org.opencv.core.Mat
import javax.imageio.ImageIO
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream
import java.awt.image.DataBufferByte
import org.opencv.core.CvType
import org.opencv.core.Core
import org.opencv.features2d.FeatureDetector
import org.opencv.core.MatOfKeyPoint
import org.opencv.features2d.Features2d
import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage
import java.io.File



object OpenCVOps {

  System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

  def imageToMat(byteArray: Array[Byte]): MatSer ={
      val bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray))
      val mat = new Mat(bufferedImage.getHeight(), bufferedImage.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
      val data = bufferedImage.getRaster().getDataBuffer.asInstanceOf[DataBufferByte].getData();
      mat.put(0, 0, data);
      new MatSer(mat);
  }

  def matToImage(mat: Mat,file: String): Boolean ={

      val imageType = BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR;
      val image = new BufferedImage(mat.cols(),mat.rows(), imageType);
      val x = image.getRaster.getDataBuffer.asInstanceOf[DataBufferByte].getData
      mat.get(0,0,x)
      val fileName = new File("file")
      ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", fileName)

  }

  def detectFeatures(mat: Mat)
  {
    val featureDetector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.SIFT)
    val matKeyPoint = new MatOfKeyPoint()
    featureDetector.detect(mat,matKeyPoint)
    println(mat.get(0, 0))
    println(matKeyPoint.toList())
    //writeToImage(mat,matKeyPoint)

  }

  def writeToImage(mat: Mat, matKeyPoint: MatOfKeyPoint){
    val outImage = new Mat()
    Features2d.drawKeypoints(mat, matKeyPoint, outImage)
    Highgui.imwrite("myfile.jpg",outImage)

  }

}
```

Here is one more example ..

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO

trait Settings {
  this: com.jme3.app.SimpleApplication =>

  protected val appSettings = new com.jme3.system.AppSettings(true)

  Seq(
    ("Width", 1920)
    , ("Height", 1080)
    , ("BitsPerPixel", 32)
    , ("Frequency", 60)
    , ("DepthBits", 24)
    , ("StencilBits", 0)
    , ("Samples", 2)
    , ("Fullscreen", false)
    , ("Title", "LW3D")
    , ("Renderer", com.jme3.system.AppSettings.LWJGL_OPENGL2)
    , ("AudioRenderer", com.jme3.system.AppSettings.LWJGL_OPENAL)
    , ("DisableJoysticks", true)
    , ("UseInput", true)
    , ("VSync", false)
    , ("FrameRate", 0)
    , ("SettingsDialogImage", "")
    , ("MinHeight", 1920)
    , ("MinWidth", 1080)
  ) foreach { case (k, v: Object) => appSettings.put(k, v) }

  appSettings.setIcons(
    List(
      ImageIO.read(getClass.getClassLoader.getResource("Yx/logo/Y256.png")),
      ImageIO.read(getClass.getClassLoader.getResource("Yx/logo/Y128.png")),
      ImageIO.read(getClass.getClassLoader.getResource("Yx/logo/Y64.png")),
      ImageIO.read(getClass.getClassLoader.getResource("Yx/logo/Y32.png")),
      ImageIO.read(getClass.getClassLoader.getResource("Yx/logo/Y16.png"))
    ).toArray
  )

  setSettings(appSettings)

  setShowSettings(false)
  setDisplayFps(true)
  setDisplayStatView(false)
  setPauseOnLostFocus(false)
}
```